# how to import named web in python

Tags: python, web.py, importerror

I tried web.py installing on Windows -64bit-

I didn't install.

Error : " ImportError: No module named 'utils' "

```
from __future__ import generators
import utils, db, net, wsgi, http, webapi, httpserver, debugerror
import template, form

import session

from utils import *
from db import *
from net import *
from wsgi import *
from http import *
from webapi import *
from httpserver import *
from debugerror import *
from application import *
from browser import *
try:
    import webopenid as openid
except ImportError:
    pass # requires openid module
```

I use python3.3

Reason of error is it which I using python3.3?

I tried install with easy_install.

But again error.

Easy_install is required python2.3.

All the problem is python 3.3?

How to import named web in python?

Thank you..!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, web.py doesn't support Python 3+

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/webpy/Qa-U1kABk4w

> Needless to say, it looks to me like there's still work to be done, but it's not impossible.  To the maintainers, do you have any plans to move towards Python 3?  I would be happy to help make this possible.

Issue tracker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/webpy/+bug/277266

> get web.py ready for Python 3.0
>   assignee:  anandology
>   importance:    Medium
>   milestone:     0.35
>   status:    Confirmed

Comment: Thank you ...

Yes I can move Python 3.

I think , using Python 2.7.

Again thank you.